# onConfigurationChanged called once every two

Tags: android, android-layout, landscape-portrait

I have two activites A B and the user can switch between them by rotating the phone from portrait to landscape

I Overrided OnConfigurationChanged  and start the new activity like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

      if (newConfig.orientation==ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER || newConfig.orientation==ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE || newConfig.orientation==ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE)
      {
            final TabGroupActivity tabGroupActivity = (TabGroupActivity) this.getParent();
            final Intent arIntent = new Intent(tabGroupActivity, ARActivity.class);
            tabGroupActivity.startActivity(arIntent);
      }



    }
```

it works fine the first time , but not the second , third is ok etc.. it works once every two

Each time it failed, the Activity A is just rotated to landscape and I noticed that my overrided OnConfigurationChanged is not called.

any suggestions ?

here is the code for ConfigurationChanged in Activity B

```
  @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

     Log.i(TAG,"onConfigurationChanged orientation  : " + newConfig.orientation);

      if (!mProgressDialog.isShowing() && (newConfig.orientation==ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT|| newConfig.orientation==ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT))
      {
            mOrientationTimer.cancel();

            this.finish();

      }


}
```

Comment: Do you have two different activities because you have different layouts applied? I'm trying to grasp why you would be starting an activity this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

add it to your Activity in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `onConfigurationChanged` in both activitivies. Probably you forgot that. or maybe you forgot to set the manifest for the two activities with `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

Comment: onConfigurationChanged  is implemented in both activities. I just edited my question. android:configChanges is also configured in the manifest file.